# Random adding within a certain time to a certain number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with something I'm working on in JavaScript/jQuery

I'd like to give a set 'destination' number, and give it a set duration, and have it so it adds up in intervals of 1 randomly throughout the duration (not equally spaced, but not all at the start, end or middle), but reaching the 'destination' number by the duration of time is up.

So, if I set a duration of 20 seconds, and a 'destination' number of 10. It will start the timer, and randomly add in intervals of 1 (following no pattern), and the duration finishes at the same time as the last number is added.

I'm really stuck with this, and not sure where to even begin.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Showing some code would help.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is:

1. Divide the duration to equal pieces (one for each increment, starting with 0, ending with the full duration)
2. Randomize the delays, but keep the same sum. If you add some random value to one delays, then subtract the same amount from delays interval.
3. Call `window.setTimeout` with all the delays. Give it a function witch increments the current value by one.

The code:

```
var start = parseInt($("#inStart").val(), 10),
    end = parseInt($("#inEnd").val(), 10),
    duration = parseInt($("#inDuration").val(), 10),
    difference = end - start,
    current = start - 1,
    step = duration * 1000 / difference,
    delays = [],
    index, amount, 
    increment = function () {
        current += 1;
        $("#outCurrent").text(current);
    };
// calculate equal delays
for (index = 0; index <= difference; index++) {
    delays.push(step * index);
}
// randomize delays, without changing the sum 
for (index = 1; index < delays.length - 2; index++) {
    amount = (Math.random() - 0.5) * step;
    delays[index] -= amount;
    delays[index+1] += amount;
}
// schedule the increment calls
for (index = 0; index < delays.length; index++) {
    window.setTimeout(increment, delays[index]);
}
```

Here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83sYF/3/), you can try it out.

Comment: Some response would have been nice.